# Facebook Like Shows a Negative Number

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The Like button on my Facebook Canvas App page is not working:
https://apps.facebook.com/bzodiac/

1. The like button under the horoscope where it says "Love Your Horoscope?" pops up the commentbox, however, it disappears right away and the count of the button is not increased.
2. If you refresh the page, the button will be grayed out as if it were "liked" already but shows "0" in count box.
3. Take your mouse over the button and click on the small "X" to "unlike" - you'll see the the count is set to -1.
4. No like feed was published to either the timeline or notification - nothing, during the whole process.
5. If I switch to "recommend" text, it works fine.

To sum up, the like button seems to be corrupted. The funny thing is that if I switch it to "Recommend", it suddenly works as expected.

This is the markup of my like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $horoscopeFBObjectUrl; ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

The like button `data-href` points to this page: https://bzodiac.herokuapp.com/fbObject.php?sign=pisces `pisces` is replace according to your zodiac sign.

Answer (score 0):

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

> You may need to add all the required og:tags if you have not already.

**Preparing for the Migration**

Facebook developers using the Like Button social plugin on their site should prepare the following when the migration takes effect:

1. All Open Graph object pages using the Like Button social plugin
   should include the fb:app_id Open Graph metatag. The Like Button
   will continue to function even if a fb:app_id metatag is not
   specified, but by specifying this metatag, developers would be able
   to test out the migration with the Like buttons they own.
2. The fb:app_id should be set to the App ID of a Facebook App
   representing the particular site or product where the Open Graph
   objects reside at.